# Doing a double induction in Coq properly

Tags: coq, proof, induction

I am trying to prove the plus_n_Sm theorem from the [Induction chapter in Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Induction.html#lab44)

```
Theorem succ_is_plus_1: forall n: nat, S n = n + 1.
Proof.
  induction n as [| n' ind_hyp].
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite <- ind_hyp. reflexivity.
Qed.

Theorem plus_n_Sm : forall n m : nat,
  S (n + m) = n + (S m).
Proof.
  induction n as [| n' ind_hyp ].
  - induction m as [| m' ind_m ].
    + simpl. reflexivity.
    + simpl. reflexivity.
  - induction m as [| m' ind_m2 ].
    + rewrite -> succ_is_plus_1 . rewrite <- plus_n_O. reflexivity.
    + rewrite -> succ_is_plus_1. rewrite <- ind_m2.
```

The output at this point is

```
1 subgoal
n' : nat
ind_hyp : forall m : nat, S (n' + m) = n' + S m
m' : nat
ind_m2 : S (S n' + m') = S n' + S m'
______________________________________(1/1)
S (S n' + m') + 1 = S n' + S (S m')
```

I'm stuck here. What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way of thinking for finding the induction proof on two variables?

Comment: You don't need to do the nested induction on `m`. And since the book explicitly asks not to publish any solutions, I'm afraid I cannot say much more.

Comment: You might want to try asking questions about SF on IRC (freenode, #coq) or https://functionalprogramming.slack.com, #coq channel (I think this one requires registration).

Comment: @AntonTrunov I did not ask for a proof script but a hint on the proper way of thinking, which would be a plain English sentence

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment said, the key is that an induction on n suffices, m can be a constant. Then the proof is straightforward.